# importing goes wrong with systemjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I'm trying to use an existing js library ([validate.js](https://validatejs.org)) in both the client and server.

I installed it using npm, and everything compiles for both server and client.
When using it in the server it works great, but when I execute it in the browser it throws an error.

The same file is used in both cases:

```
import validate = require("validate.js");

export function RequestValidator(data: any): any {
    return (validate as any)(data, constraints, { allowEmpty: true });
}
```

`validate` is asserted to `any` becuase otherwise I get:

> TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

The `.d.ts` I'm using is:

```
declare module "validate.js" {
    export interface ValidateJS {
        (attributes: any, constraints: any, options?: any): any;
        async(attributes: any, constraints: any, options?: any): Promise<any>;
        single(value: any, constraints: any, options?: any): any;
    }

    export const validate: ValidateJS;
    export default validate;
}
```

The module only exports a function, and that works well in the server, but in the client when invoking this function I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: validate is not a function(…)
```

The code is compiled using target `commonjs` for the server:

```
"use strict";
const validate = require("validate.js");
...
```

And `system` for the client:

```
System.register(["validate.js"], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var validate;
    ...

    return {
        setters:[
            function (validate_1) {
                validate = validate_1;
            }],
    ...
```

When debugging it, `validate` indeed isn't a function it's:

```
validate: r
    EMPTY_STRING_REGEXP: (...)
    get EMPTY_STRING_REGEXP: function()
    set EMPTY_STRING_REGEXP: function()
    Promise: (...)
    get Promise: function()
    set Promise: function()
    __useDefault: (...)
    get __useDefault: function()
    set __useDefault: function()
    async: (...)
    get async: function()
    set async: function()
    capitalize: (...)
    get capitalize: function()
    set capitalize: function()
    cleanAttributes: (...)
    get cleanAttributes: function()
    set cleanAttributes: function()
    ...
```

Any idea what's going on and why it behaves this way in the browser?

Comment: See the last sentence in this paragraph on CommonJS: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#commonjs. SystemJS doesn't load CommonJS modules exactly the same way as NodeJS does. There's `@node` however I have no personal experience with this kind of black magic.

Comment: @martin well, isn't that dandy.  I especially like: "this should only be used when absolutely necessary as it stops code from being universal, and makes it only compatible with NodeJS". So now I'm forced to use `jspm` as well?

Comment: I've never used that option myself, I just remember is saw it mentioned there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile with `"module": "system"`, node-compatible import

```
import validate = require("validate.js");
```

no longer works - the value you are getting for `validate` is a module, not a function. This may be a bug in typescript, or it could be by design - I don't know. (update: from github comment addressed to JsonFreeman [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242#issuecomment-78154149), it looks like it's by design: `you get the module object with a set of properties including one named default`).

There are several ways around this.

First, you can do easy conversion yourself - the function that you need is provided as `default` property of the module, so this line will fix it:

```
validate = validate.default ? validate.default : validate;
```

Or, you can compile with `"module": "commonjs"` even for the browser, so typescript will generate working code, and systemjs will detect format for your modules automatically.

Or finally, you could still compile with `"module": "system"`, but import `validate.js` as it's intended in its typings:

```
import validate from 'validate.js';
```

That way you don't have to do any casts to `any`, and typescript will generate necessary access for `default` property, but the drawback is that   it will not work at all in node when imported that way.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the `validate.default` option. It would have been great to import it like the last option you gave, but unfortunately the same code needs to run in both the browser and node.